# How to change activity from onPostExecute() method using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an **activity** called `LoginActivity` in my app (using kotlin). This will send a post request to an API as an **Async task**. I want to change the **activity** from `onPostExecute` method to `MainWindowActivity` after getting response from the API.
I cannot change the activity:

```
 val intent = Intent(this, MainWindowActivity::class.java)
 startActivity(intent)
```

since `this` will only return `LoginActivity.PostJsonAsync`

(`PostJsonAsync` is a class which `extends` `AsyncTask`)

Comment: just try to change val intent = Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainWindowActivity::class.java)

Comment: I tried it earlier but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To refer an outer class instance (LoginActivity) from inner class (PostJsonAsync) in Kotlin, you must make your class as inner (they can access outer class instance) by adding `inner` keyword before class.

```
inner class PostJsonAsync : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: Add inner keyword before class PostJsonAsync: AsyncTask.

Comment: Working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
val intent = Intent(name_of_your_activity:class.this, MainWindowActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: It is not Working.i tried it and i got an error while building this as:`The expression cannot be a selector (occur after a dot)`

Comment: @EntertainmentS I edited my answer, the point is to link to current Activity, where the code is + plus use **this** reference.